# echo value from table when clicking on a button on another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Following is the table i created for displaying the Restaurant Name, Location and Menu for table owners.
Now each of the row for the column Menu have Button as values.
My table is ready with perfect values.

## NOW MY PROBLEM IS HOW TO DO:-

Upon clicking the button corresponding to the each Restaurant, a new File(openmenu.php) will open and will echo the Restaurant Name, Mobile Number of that Restaurant and the menu.
But so far, on clicking every Button ,I can only display above entries of the Last row of the table. Help Me Out. I am new to php.

## table.php

```
<?php


include 'nav.php';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM owners';

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (!$query) {
die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">

<style> 
    .data-table{
 width: 1024px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    text-align:center;
     border: 1px solid firebrick;
    background-color: white;

}
td,th{
    border: 1px solid firebrick; padding: 3px 2px 1px 1px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<article>

<table class="data-table">

    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Restuarant Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Menu</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

   $_SESSION['resphone'] = $row['resphone'];
      $_SESSION['restaur'] = $row['restaur'];
        echo '<tr>


                <td>'.$row['restaur'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['loc'].'</td>

                <td style="background-color:firebrick;"><form method="post" action="openmenu.php?id=$row[restaur]"><input value="<?php echo $restaur;?>" type="hidden">
 <input type="submit"  value="View"></form></td>
            </tr>';


    }


        ?>

            </tbody>

</table>


</form>







</article>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## openmenu.php

```
<?php 


include('nav.php');


?>

<html>
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <style>
table, td {
border: none;
 text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">




<article>

<form  method="get" align="center"  action="" class="formwrap" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h1><?php $restaur = $_SESSION['restaur'];
echo $restaur ;?></h1>
<h1>Call to Order:</h1>
<?php $resphone = $_SESSION['resphone'];

echo $resphone;

?>

<br>
<br>
 <?php


 $sql = "select img from owners where restaur ='$restaur'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 $image_src2 = "upload/".$row['img'];


?>
<img src='<?php echo $image_src2; ?>' >   

    </form>

</article>


 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the session or cookies ...

Comment: Make it a link to `another.php?id=$row[resphone]` (or whatever). Or make it a `<form>` if it absolutely has to be an `<input>`. This is the most basic use of PHP, really.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could solve this problem.

You could make a `<form>` with your view button ( if this view button not already has a form ) and give this a method like: `POST` or `GET`.

This would look like: `<form method="POST">` *or* `<form method="GET">`

[*Docs to POST and GET*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

I think your view button could look something like this

```
<form method="post" action="OtherPHPpage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="view" value="<?php echo $row['resphone']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
```

*This will redirect you to your other page and you will be able to `post` the value of the `hidden input type`*

You can also use `php` sessions even though this is not the best solution in your case

```
session_start();
```

Put this on the top of your php page

```
// set the session
$_SESSION['variablename'] = $row['resphone'];

// retrieve the session variable
$whatever = $_SESSION['variablename'];
```

Comment: Don't introduce sessions unless you have to. This really doesn't seem like a use case for sessions. Plain request parameters will probably do.

Comment: @deceze that is true... Using a form might be the better solution now that you are saying

Comment: @deceze is right, query parameter should be fine here, although I dont think this is worth a downvote, since it is a solution to OPs stated problem.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt i will add multiple solutions to my answer with several explanations to it